# Should questions be downvoted just because they already have an answer? (perspective of a newbie)

Tags: discussion

Often my questions get downvoted because they already have an answer.

However, I always search around and look before posting any question. Sometimes, it’s difficult to know *exactly* what to search for when you have a question, especially in something like programming. **For example**, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677226/python-list-generation-using-showing-strange-behaviour-arrij-indexing-t) question which already had answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). But as you can see, the question titles were radically different, and I did not get anything in my “similar questions” either.

And now, I get an ominous banner saying that I may be *banned* from asking questions because they are of poor quality. As I am a newbie, I don’t have much to contribute in terms of answers, and if I get question-blocked, then I will effectively be unable to use Stack Overflow, unless I create another account.

Comment: If I find a duplicate within 5-10 minutes of a user posting a question, there's a strong chance I'll downvote the post. It depends on how easy it was to find based on some key words in the question and the question itself.

Comment: When you have some strange bug, how exactly would you search for it? I mean the probability is high that the keywords that you think of are different from the ones that somebody else might think of...

Comment: @xrisk if WE can find a duplicate within 5-10 minutes, why can't you? that's the point people are trying to make here. You say "it's hard", and if we manage to find it quick... then you probably didn't search that much now did you?

Comment: Not trying to argue here, but since you already know the solution to my question, that’s why you can find a duplicate?

Comment: Wow, now I’m getting question-banned for sure :(

Comment: Meta is different. Don't worry about votes here.

Comment: @xrisk yes, it makes it easier, definitely. You know how I ask questions on stack? I put up a draft, and I take a full week at least of research before I post it. 7 Full days. In these 7 days, if that question already exists on stack, I WILL have found it.

Comment: @Patrice interesting I’ll try that next time.

Comment: [Google search "python list strange behaviour".](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=python+list+strange+behaviour) Click first link. Yes, that's a search with a vague subset of your title. If your question is answerable by googling its title, you haven't searched hard enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+list+weird+behaviour

Comment: @xrisk Click the second link. Also, don't depend only on the local search - Google is rich for a reason.

Comment: @Veedrac ok I’ve learnt my lesson. Now, I will leave before this question gets even more down votes.

Comment: @xrisk Don't worry about Meta downvotes. They don't count towards anything (except badges?), and aren't a comment on question quality (just agreement). Eg. on this question they probably mean "I think this was handled appropriately; no changes are needed."

Comment: Your *very first search* should be Google. It searches far wider than a search here, and if the answer is here Google will find it. If you haven't spent at least an hour or two trying to find it on Google before posting here, and I can find answers without even being familiar with the topic, you can bet I'll downvote your question. We should be *the last resort*, after you've exhausted *every other means* of finding a solution. If you haven't looked everywhere else as well as here, you haven't made an adequate effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: _But as you can see, the question titles were radically different_ One thing you'll want to do is make the question title as specific as possible. The phrase "showing strange behavior" is way too vague. It's also a phrase that's used too often: three of the "related" questions use the word "strange".

Comment: @patrice, if everyone has a week for every problem stackoverflow might not be this much famous or relevant. I often have to learn new things, evaluate pro--cons, other options & then implement some business story with test cases. Seven days are not given even for that.

Comment: @PranavSingh but Stack is NOT a helpdesk, or made to help with time sensitive issues. If you need to evaluate pro-cons and ask on stack, it's off-topic. Your dependency on timely answers should NOT be a reason for me to rush to answer you. I'm sorry, but I don't consider what you bring here relevant. I understand the issue, but I don't think it's Stack's problem

Comment: @Patrice, I think off-topic talk in comment. :) I want to convey sometime there is urgency & we don't have 7 Days. I am not defending adding duplicate questions.

Comment: @PranavSingh again, why should it be stack's problem? The purpose of stack is not to help meet your deadlines but provide a good repo for Q &A. Time should never be a reason not to do your research. To me, there is no justification that stands if you are in a hurry or not. stack is not a help desk. Urgency is NOT a reson to post here

Comment: Sometimes I have the same problem. It's sad you're still getting all these downvotes. The SE community can be torture sometimes

Answer (score 12):

> *"Should questions be downvoted just because they already have an answer?"*

If the answer is easy to find by all the indicators given regarding questions, shown in the related section, and given while typing a question, most probably yes!

Because that's an indication of *low research efforts* done. Remind the tooltip on the downvote button:

> *`This question doesn't show any research effort ...`*

---

> *"(perspective of a newbie)"*

Doesn't matter if it was asked by a *"newbie"* or [*@Jon Skeet*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Bad questions are bad questions, and should be downvoted and declined.